# php data clean HTML

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I having little problem in my project. Here is situation:

I have a video description field coming from database and then I am assigning that value to javascript variable like this:

```
var description="<?=$video->videos_desc?>";
```

Now the problem I am facing is when I assign description in these format

```
var description="Hey Michel's video"; // It works ok

var description='Hey Michel's video'; // Doesn't work

var description='Hey see this "funny" video'; //  It works ok

var description="Hey see this "funny" video"; // Doesn't work
```

As data is coming from the database I can not change it as it is huge. Is there any quick solution or php function to clean or properly format so the javascript will work without problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the php str_replace method:

```
var description = "<?=str_replace('"', '\\"', $video->videos_desc)?>";
```

Answer (score 2):

I think **[json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)** will be best choice here. It will not only take care of quotes, but of newlines too.

Answer (score 0):

`addslashes` should do the trick. See [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php).

```
<?=addslashes($video->videos_desc)?>
```